# does having mutliple OR Cluses slow down a query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, where-clause

i have a function which turns this string

```
[games]|[nexis core]|[core]|[lemure lemure]|[chrome tower dlc]
```

into this where clause

```
WHERE 
(
    main.tags LIKE '%[games]%' OR 
    main.tags LIKE '%[nexis core]%' OR 
    main.tags LIKE '%[core]%' OR 
    main.tags LIKE '%[lemure lemure]%' OR 
    main.tags LIKE '%[chrome tower dlc]%'
)
```

in the table it's doing the search in, a record will has a `tags` field like the following

```
[boss]|[lemure lemure]|[astra]|[divine]|[kamidori]|[3rd party]|[razil]|[core]
```

so when the above where clause runs, it can search the `tags` fields and the order of the tags will have no effect on the search

the reason why i encase every tag in `[]` and do a `LIKE` cluse with it included is if someone searches for the tag `party` they may get `[3rd party] [party members] [nunnally's battle party] [battle party reality marble]` which all are completely different things as `[3rd party]` is used to describe a battle which a 3rd group participates which isn't allied with the player party or enemy party while `[battle party reality marble]` is used to describe an ability

i separate each tag with a `|` so that i can explode the string in PHP when i pull it from the database and output each tag to the page, similar to the suggest tags when a question is asked here

now, while i can impose a limit to the number of tags a use can use in a search like how this site limits the number of tags used in a question to 5 i want to try and avoid that if possible, the `WHERE` clause i generate can have technically infinite `OR`s because of how it generates

i am wondering, can a prepared statement in mysqli slow down if i use too many `OR` in the query

Comment: What's going to slow your query is being unable to use any indexes because of the `LIKE '%...%'` constructs. You really should switch over to using a FULLTEXT index system, which is designed for these kinds of queries. What's also slowing down your query is using an incorrect design and putting all those tags into a SINGLE field in a SINGLE record. You should normalize your design and separate them into a child table.

Comment: Of course, eventually it would start to slow down as you add more clauses, the main cost of performance is the LIKE statements, not so much the OR by itself. FULLTEXT would be better, and if you're going to have more than a couple million rows you would need to use something like Apache SOLR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The performance impact is not because of the `OR` combination, but because of the `LIKE '%search'`, which cannot use an index.

And really, your database is badly normalized - and because of this it is harder to get what you need, and it takes more performance than necessary.